# cut the percentage from the variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, numbers, percentage

I check the cell for a blank in the database. If it's not empty, I cut off 5 percent, if not, I skip it, but I have a problem. Maybe I'm not checking for emptiness. I have after `null ? ''` brackets are going and they my percent stops working and outputs me just `10-2`.

```
let one = User[0].percent // - 10% (variable one value: 100)
let two = checkingOptions.options == null ? '' : -5 // - 5%
let three = checkingFly[2] == null ? '' : - checkingFly.percent // - 2%
let mp = + one + two + three
console.log(mp)
```

I want him to calculate for me correctly
`10-2 = 8`,
But I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: kind of confusing. what is `chevar` and what is `men` variables

Comment: @CotyEmbry corrected a little bit

Comment: so `User[0].percent` has a value of '10%' `checkingOptions.options` has a value of null or '5%' and `checkingFly[2]` has a value of null or '2%' ?

Answer (score 0):

The + operator is overloaded - for numbers it does addition, for strings it does concatenation. And for mixed values it coerces them to be the same type one way or the other.

One or more of your values are probably strings. Figure out which ones are strings and convert them like this:

```
const allPercent = Number(User[0].percent)
```